# Redirect home item not working with SxA

Tags: sxa

We are using SXA 1.9 and I can reproduce the behaviour on a vanilla sitecore instance with SXA 1.9 installed.

I've created a tenant called "my-tenant and" a site called "my-site"
The start page in site grouping is set to the "my-site" item (not to home).
Under "my-site", there are basically 2 home items called: firsthome and secondhome
whenever the domain mysite.de gets called there is a redirect mapping defined with a regex expression: `^/(.*)?$` that redirects to "firsthome" item.
Everything is working perfect so far. But as soon as I place a rendering onto a page a javascript error occurs and the variants are not visible.
The javascript error happens in variantswitcher.js line 27.

```
Uncaught TypeError: variants.some is not a function
```

Do you know of any other possibility how to deal with 2 start items? because we don't want to have "firsthome" visible in the url when visiting "secondhome".
the url structure should be like this:

- mysite.de -> redirect to mysite.de/firsthome
- mysite.de/firsthome
- mysite.de/secondhome

Comment: Sounds to me like these are two different sites. Any reason you want to keep this as just 1 site with 2 subsections?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what your tree structure looks like? Also for the settings are?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just moved the firsthome and secondhome under "home" item and changed the home item template to a redirect template. All I need to do is now change the 302 redirect into an 301 somehow

[image]